# Please explain what does exec, trap, mknod, tee do

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I have a script that I got from one of the websites.It gave "Hello" as output when I ran it, but I couldn't understand the working of the script.

Can anyone explain what the script is actually doing?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello

if test -t 1; then
  # Stdout is a terminal.
  exec >log
else
  # Stdout is not a terminal.
  npipe=/tmp/$$.tmp
  trap "rm -f $npipe" EXIT
  mknod $npipe p
  tee <$npipe log &
  exec 1>&-
  exec 1>$npipe
fi

echo goodbye
```

Comment: That is using a bunch of reasonably "advanced" shell scripting features (and, ugh, insecurely). It also looks needlessly complicated...

Comment: @derobert I think the most insecure part about this script is "I got a script off a website and I ran it, but I don't know how it works"

Comment: did you try looking at the `man` pages for each of these commands first? Generally the best starting place for what a command does.

Answer (score 6):

The script is probably an example, and you are expected to change the `echo goodbye` to do something more.

Let us assume that the script is called `demo`. When you run it then as you have seen it first outputs "hello". It then sees if the output is going to the terminal or not, with the intention of deciding if you are running

```
demo
```

or

```
demo | some other program
```

If it is the former then it just send the output of the rest of the file to the file called `log`. If the latter then if creates a `named pipe` and starts a `tee` process to copy everything written to the named pipe to both the output of the `demo` script (so `some other prog` will get it) and to the file called `log`. It then arranges to send the output of the rest of the file to this named pipe. It also arranges that when `demo` finishes it will remove the named pipe.

The line `exec 1>&-` is not needed.

The net result of all of this is that the word "goodbye" is written to the file "log". If you ran `demo | cat` you would see both "hello" and "goodbye" on your screen.

As @derobert points out in the comments, the named pipe has a predictable name. Depending on the setting of `umask` this might allow someone to corrupt the output of `demo` either by reading it (so `tee` doesn't see it) or adding extra stuff for `tee` to copy. This is in addition to a number of standard attacks that can be used against known or predicable names. Soft or hard links can be set up in advance to cause other files to be opened or truncated. On my linux system the mknod will fail if the file already exists, but as the script ignores this error then the `exec 1>$npipe` will be executed.

Comment: I'd suggest you mention the predictable temporary file name, and the possible security implications.

Comment: @derobert done, probably a waste as this question is downvoted but we have tried.

Comment: There is more to that security problem—someone could throw a symlink there. `mknod` will then fail, but the script doesn't check for errors... and then the redirect will (depending on the setting of `/proc/sys/fs/protected_symlinks`) happily follow the symlink. Anyway, people should vote the answer independent of the question—and I think there is even a badge if you get enough upvotes on your answer to a downvoted question.

Comment: The badge is `reversal`, and needs +20 on the answer. There have only been two awarded.